# My kitten isn’t as energetic as my other kitten. Is something wrong?

Tags: cats, behavior

My kitten Leo (male) for one  looks smaller than the other kitten Mimi but I got them both from the shelter the same day, from the same cage. Leo follows us around, meows, loves cuddles and purrs. Mimi is female and plays 24/7, she plays by herself all the time. Mimi and Leo used to play a lot and lately Leo just wants to be near us and nap most the time. Sometimes Mimi wants to play with Leo but he doesn’t give back the same energy so she goes off to play by herself. What could be wrong with my cat?

Comment: Changes in behavior and lethargy are medical red flags, consult your vet ASAP.

Comment: I agree with seeing a vet just in case, but I’ve had kittens go through major growth spurts and simply have no energy left for anything other than eating and sleeping.